# AnimatedContainer causing overflow

Tags: flutter

I'm using an AnimatedContainer to create a slide animation on a widget that be displayed when a button is pressed, this widget get all body size. But because of this widget didn't resize with animated container a overflow occurs, how can i fix that?

```
AnimatedContainer(
duration: 300.milliseconds,
width:
    store.isExpanded ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width : 0,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey.shade900.withOpacity(.4)),
  ],
),
child: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.shade900.withOpacity(.4),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: ConsumoDetailPanel(
          mesa: widget.mesa,
          store: store,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
          highlightColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
          onTap: () => store.toggleIsExpanded(false),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that using SizeTransition instead of AnimationContainer:

```
late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: 500.milliseconds,
  );
late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _controller,
  curve: Curves.linear,
);
```

...

```
SizeTransition(
  sizeFactor: _animation,
  axis: Axis.horizontal,
  axisAlignment: -1,
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey.shade900.withOpacity(.4),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: ConsumoDetailPanel(
            mesa: widget.mesa,
            store: store,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            highlightColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            onTap: () => _controller.reverse(),
            // store.toggleIsExpanded(false),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```